# Stack matrices with different number of rows in R

Tags: arrays, r, combinations

Sorry if too naive but I cannot find a simple answer. I have two matrices:

```
> F5.Titers.reticulata1
         3d    6d    12d     18d     24d
 [1,]  6.34 15.64 256.37 1025.82 1025.34
 [2,] 12.35 28.64 198.64 1658.41  970.00
 [3,] 10.22 13.52 364.35  896.64 1236.69
 [4,]  8.34  7.68 298.78 1536.17 1532.44
 [5,]  6.16 28.64 345.11 1223.35  899.31
 [6,]  7.37  6.45 287.46  956.33 2025.35

> F5.Titers.tankan1
         3d    6d    12d     18d     24d
 [1,]  6.35 15.34 315.36 1425.36 1102.13
 [2,] 15.34 20.15 485.35  996.35  969.97
 [3,] 10.21 25.55 263.35  568.36 1045.09
```

And you like to have a stacked one:

```
> Joint.matrix.hurray

[[reticulata1]]

         3d    6d    12d     18d     24d
 [1,]  6.34 15.64 256.37 1025.82 1025.34
 [2,] 12.35 28.64 198.64 1658.41  970.00
 [3,] 10.22 13.52 364.35  896.64 1236.69
 [4,]  8.34  7.68 298.78 1536.17 1532.44
 [5,]  6.16 28.64 345.11 1223.35  899.31
 [6,]  7.37  6.45 287.46  956.33 2025.35


 [[tankan1]]
         3d    6d    12d     18d     24d
 [1,]  6.35 15.34 315.36 1425.36 1102.13
 [2,] 15.34 20.15 485.35  996.35  969.97
 [3,] 10.21 25.55 263.35  568.36 1045.09
```

Please note they have different numbers of rows but same number of cols. I'd like to have them stacked, if possible keeping numbers as numeric and the names.  Thanks

Comment: did you try out rbind?

Comment: When you are writing, `list(F5.Titers.reticulata1, F5.Titers.tankan1)`, the matrix doesn't keep the numeric format ?

Comment: Sorry @MbrMbr in fact now I see it is keeping the numbers format, I was having problems with list() from before from another conversion and mixed this up. I will adjust the question accordingly so it helps others -- the answer below was very useful for me. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to create a `list` of `matrices`

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern = "F5\\.Titers"))
names(lst) <- sub("F5.Titers.", "", names(lst))
```

Comment: This is one very powerful solution! Great, it will help me organise all my data sets, very nice indeed. Thanks